# Powershell: Is it possible to list all folders on a san ? (Vmware)

Tags: powershell, vsphere

I've noticed that sometimes a dead folder gets left behind on a Lun when a VM has been moved, or sometimes by Veeam when a job has moved.

I'm after a way of getting the top level folders for all the available luns on a virtual centre (5.1)
Then I can write something to look for duplicate folders.

I'm hoping its easy but so far I have not found an easy way to do it ?
Any ideas ?

Answer (score 0):

The best way to do this would be to use VMWare Power CLI (Command Line Interface) in order to retrieve the listing of all the LUN's and folders on the LUN's.

Here's something to get you started: [Using PowerShell to View Datastore and Virtual Machine Space Usage Information in VMware](http://pipe2text.com/?page_id=2673)

Comment: Thanks for the info but I can already do this :(
That command will show the folder of where a VM is currently registered to the Virtualcentre

However it will not show a dead folder that has been left behind on a different lun 
by an issue, vmotion, Netbackup, etc 

I'm now thinking of running a recursive "ls" on a host and exporting it to a text file. 
Then Importing the file into a powershell script to extract the foldernames.
A sort and then an array comparison could produce what I am after ...well maybe !

Cheers